# How to get first satisfied return value for a collection?

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming

I am new to Scala. I have a HashSet, when I iterate over it, I apply a recursive function to the element. How can I get the first satisfied function return value?

I tried collections.find(...).map(...), but cannot extract the return value inside the function in find(), and I don't want map to run these recursive function again.

```py
def Rec(myObject, acc: list):
    if myObject.size == 1:
        return acc
    elif len(myObject.myList) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        for e in myObject.myList:
            #func is another function that create a new object whose size is smaller and changes myList attribute
            newObject = func(myObject, e)
            acc.append(e)
            res = Rec(newObject, acc)
            if res:
                return res
        return None
```

So, my question is how to convert above python code to idiomatic scala code.

EDIT:
For example:
I want to write like this:

```
list.find(e=>Rec(e).isDefined).map(e=>Rec(e).get)
```

Rec() is a function that returns an option. And I want to extract the result of Rec(e) in find(...) when it finds, so I don't have to recalculate it in the map(...)

Comment: Take a look at the `find` method. Also, some inputs and expected output would be helpful for others.

Comment: you can probably use `.dropWhile` as well: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#dropWhile(p:A=>Boolean):C

Comment: and `.indexWhere`: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#indexWhere(p:A=>Boolean):Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `List` of elements of some (unspecified) type and you want to process each element only until the first non-None result.

Something like this?

```
myObject.myList        //List of elements
        .view          //evaluate lazily
        .flatMap(rec)  //pass to the rec() func, flatten away all None results
        .headOption    //Some(<1st good result>) or None
```

In this case `rec()` is invoked only until the first non-None result is returned, or until the end of the list if no non-None result is produced.